# XCode and SFML - where to put templates?

Tags: xcode, macos, sfml

I've tried to install SFML for XCode for days now and I just can't get it right. I've read multiple tutorials yet none seem to be updated for the latest release of XCode. I downloaded the 32/64bit version of SFML and copied the libraries to the appropriate folders (which existed). When I'm going to install the project templates, however, the folder mentioned in the official tutorial doesn't exist. I've tried different folders but it won't work.

> "However, in order to make using SFML easier, we also provide project templates for Xcode. To use them, copy the "SFML Window-based Application" and "SFML Graphics-based Application" directories from SFML-x.y/build/xcode/templates to "/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application", as well as the "SFML Tool" directory to "/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Command Line Utility"

In my Xcode folder there's a "Templates" folder and underneath that "Project Templates" and "File Templates". Under each of them there's a "Mac" and "Base" folder and then tons of different folders.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

You should install your templates in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/` (`~` stands for your home directory). However, project templates for Xcode 4 are different than those for Xcode 3. You may have to rework them a bit. See [here](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/) for details.